# Laravel Nova upload image and save url to database

Tags: laravel, image, file-upload, cloudinary, laravel-nova

I have been attempting to upload an image to cloudinary, which is pretty easy. My problem is how do I go about saving the url to the database instead of the image? I was suppose to use https://github.com/Silvanite/nova-field-cloudinary, but the documentation is pretty slim. Also, I would like to save the image with original file name (storeOriginalName).

```
CloudinaryImage::make('Featured Image')
```

Nova's version:

```
Image::make('Featured Image')
        ->disk('cloudinary')
```

`https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/resources/file-fields.html#images`
`https://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_image_and_video_upload#upload_response`
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#storing-uploaded-files

**Update.** This works for storing original file name, but still not sure how to grab url and save it to featured_image column:

```
    CloudinaryImage::make('Featured Image')
            ->storeAs(function (Request $request) {
                return $request->featured_image->getClientOriginalName();
            }),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to store the remote URL with Cloudinary. The public id returned by the component is used to generate the final URL when you output the image somewhere using one of the ways described in the documentation ...

```php
// Using the helper (with transformation)

return cloudinary_image($this->featured_image, [
    "width" => 200,
    "height" => 200,
    "crop" => "fill",
    "gravity" => "auto",
])

// Using the Storage Facade (without transformation)

return Storage::disk('cloudinary')->url($this->featured_image);

// Using the Storage Facade (with transformation)

return Storage::disk('cloudinary')->url([
    'public_id' => $this->featured_image,
    'options' => [
        "width" => 200,
        "height" => 200,
        "crop" => "fill",
        "gravity" => "auto",
    ],
])
```

Or you could generate the URL yourself as per the Cloudinary documentation https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_optimization

It would be helpful if you could expand on why you need to save the full URL as there may be an alternative solution.

Comment: Thanks Marco! The reason this was requested is because all previous images in the project were created with a hard coded url added to a text column across multiple models, not an uploaded image. There is fear other issues will occur (with old data having url links for the text column) if it is changed, my job was to only update specific models, not all. My suggestion was to update the entire project to use the same method for all images across all models, upload with cloudinary, S3 or whatever they so choose to use, but keep it all the same. I'm hoping we will update the entire project.

Answer (score 0):

The upload response contains an url field. Here is an example:

```
{
 public_id: 'sample',
 version: '1312461204',
 width: 864,
 height: 564,
 format: 'jpg',
 created_at: '2017-08-10T09:55:32Z',
 resource_type: 'image',
 tags: [], 
 bytes: 9597, 
 type: 'upload', 
 etag: 'd1ac0ee70a9a36b14887aca7f7211737', 
 url: '<url>',
 secure_url: '<secure_url>',
 signature: 'abcdefgc024acceb1c1baa8dca46717137fa5ae0c3',
 original_filename: 'sample'
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did see that (my link included in description), but how do I acces that and then save it to 'featured_image' column? ```Cloudinary::make(‘featured_image’)->storeAs(function (Request $request) {

  return $request->featured_image->getClientOriginalName();
});```